# Material-ui XGrid stops rendering when adding the useApiRef to the component

Tags: material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTable } from '../hooks/UtilityHooks/useTable';

import { XGrid, useApiRef} from '@material-ui/x-grid';



const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
    const form = useForm(state, setState);
    const productionTable = useTable('Production', form);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

    const tableRef = useApiRef();

    
    
    React.useEffect(() => {

        (async() => {

            try{
                setLoading(true)
                const data = await get(); `Fetching data here`
                setState(data);
                setLoading(false)
          
            }catch(err){
                setLoading(false)

            }

        })()
 
    }, [])

 


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <GridContainer style={{height: "calc(100vh - 170px)", overflowY: "auto", padding: "10px"}}>
                <GridItem>

                    <XGrid 
                    apiRef={tableRef}
                    columns={productionTable.columns}
                    rows={state}
                    loading={loading}
                    pagination={true}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[15,25,50]}
                    pageSize={15}

                />

     
                </GridItem>
            </GridContainer>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default Dashboard;
```

1/10 refreshes table do render. But 9/10 I have to trigger the render by clicking on the screen.

In useTable I have a function to run to set the columns along with other stuff.
It does this perfectly well until I add the useApiRef to subscribe to column reorder changes etc. to set some user state with the new colorder/colwidth etc';
When I log out the ref I can see that the data and the columns are there - but view is not updating accordingly.

[Image of the table and ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBNiQ.png)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to persist user changes of the table. Were you ever able to figure out how to do this? I'm hoping to do the same with x-grid and need to save user changes to a database for future renders of tables.